# How to count asymptotic notation in this code_

Tags: python, complexity-theory

```
def func(s):
    for i in range(s):
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(s):
                for k in range(10000):
                    print("ffff")
```

In this code what is the asymptotic time complexity of `func` with respect to s?

And how many times is "ffff" printed with respect to `s`?

I tried `n`, `n**2`, `1000*n**2` and I'm about to give up.

Comment: *"I tried `n`, `n**2`, `1000*n**2`"*: how did you try? What happened that you considered it wrong?

Comment: Please don't ask Stack Overflow to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def func(s):
    for i in range(s):
        if i == 0:
            for j in range(s):
                for k in range(10000):
                    print("ffff")
```

The code consists of three nested loops:
The outermost loop runs s times.
The middle loop runs s times for the first iteration of the outer loop (`i == 0`).
The innermost loop runs a constant number of times (`10_000`) for each iteration of the middle loop.

Now, let's calculate the time complexity:

The outermost loop runs `s` times.
The middle loop runs `s` times, but only for the first iteration of the outer loop (`i == 0`).
The innermost loop runs a constant number of times (`10_000`) for each iteration of the middle loop, which is limited to just one iteration (`i == 0`).
So, the total number of times "ffff" is printed is

```
1 * 1 * 10_000 = 10_000
```

which is independent of `s`. Therefore, the number of times "ffff" is printed is a constant and does not depend on the value of `s`.

As for the time complexity with respect to `s`, it's primarily determined by the outermost loop, which runs `s` times. Therefore, the asymptotic time complexity of the `func` function is `O(s)`.

Comment: *The total amount of times "ffff" is printed is ... 10_000* is obviously wrong. Your final answer part is correct about `O(s)` complexity - how can `O(s)` code log fixed amount of iterations?